# What values should I keep in my Transposition Table?

Tags: algorithm, artificial-intelligence, computer-science

I'm making a program to play Connect 6, a variation of Connect 4 where you have to get a sequence of 6 in a row, and pieces can be placed in *any* unoccupied space no matter how many pieces are below it.

I'm currently using Minimax with Alpha-Beta Pruning. I want to use a transposition table to speed things up.

However, I obviously can't keep all possible boards in my transposition table, so how do I decide which ones I keep?

My transposition table is currently a [1000000][4] array, so can stores 4 million board states.

**Ideas so far**

I have absolutely nothing. I thought about this for a while, but couldn't think of anything.

**EDIT**

The board size can range from 7 to 19.
I access the array by doing hashKey % 1000000 to get the first index, and then loop through the remaining 4 to find the state I'm looking for. I'm using Zobrist Hashing.

Comment: If you use an array, how are you doing the lookup? What is the board size?

Comment: How do you encode the board state?

Comment: @StefanHaustein I use Zobrist Hashing.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just see the table as a cache and go for FIFO or LRU?

Comment: I don't have the time, knowledge, or programming skills to implement either of those. I'm stuck with what I have :)

Comment: Well if you don't have the time to implement anything then why ask in the first place?

Comment: Sorry, I misread Wikipedia's description of FIFO. From what I understood FIFO works by processing the oldest entry first right? That wouldn't work, because some old entries are used very frequently, but newer ones are rarely used. Using FIFO wouldn't allow me to take the popularity of that board state into account.

Comment: LRU wouldn't work because a board state that is extremely popular would be discarded over a state thats rarely used just because the less popular state was used more recently.

Comment: The probability for frequently used states to be kicked out would be lower because if they are frequently accessed they frequently get to the top of the list. So what you describe can happen, but it is unlikely, in particular for large caches.

Comment: If I use LRU, and want to add a new state. I have a choice of replacing the element that was used last. Why would I want to replace it? Theres no reason for me to believe the new state will be more popular than the currently least recently used state.

Comment: well you store 4 000 000 entries and you don't want to give a new element a chance at the cost of throwing one out that has not been used for 4 000 000 steps?

Comment: Its 4, not 4 million. The new element has to be placed in 1 of 4 buckets in the index correlating with its hash key, not a random spot in the hash table.

Comment: Well why not go for LRU anyway and see how it works if you don't have a better idea? You could also have an access counter for each of the four. When you need to delete one, weight it by how recently it was incremented to decide which one must go...